# A(n easy ?) partial differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

This might be a classic partial differential equation, but I couldn't find anything on the Internet:

Find all the functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ verifying $ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x) = 0 $.

I do understand this means that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \langle \nabla f(x), x \rangle = 0$, but I still do not see how to proceed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule, especially the Generalizations section.

Comment: Hint: It means that the directional derivative in the radial direction is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned in effect that all directional derivatives along rays from the origin are zero. So $f$ doesn't change on such rays. So for example, $f(x)=f(x/3)=f(2x)$ (assuming the domain of $f$ includes a ray segment through those points). In fact to standardize things let's say $f$ is differentiable and defined everywhere except $0$, and $f(x)=f(x/|x|)$. There is no other requirement. $f$ is determined by its values on a sphere.

However, if you insist that $f$ be defined and continuous at the origin, I think that forces $f$ to be constant on the sphere too, so constant everywhere.